# Найти самую часто встречающуюся подстроку заданной длины k в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, биоинформатика

Взял курс по биоинформатике на coursera. Есть задачка, которую я не могу решить. Смысл в том что у нас есть две переменные:

1. перечень букв в одно длинное слово, в котором есть повторяющиеся сочетания букв (напр.ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT и CATG GCAT)
2. Цифра которая задает количество повторяющихся букв(в примере выше задана цифра
3. Надо узнать какое из сочетаний самое повторяющееся. Я нашел решение и не могу понять одну строку:

   ```
   Count = CountDict(Text, k)
   ```

   У меня выкидывает ошибку, а ее смысл как я понимаю в создании словаря.

   ```
   # Input:  A string Text and an integer k
   # Output: A list containing all most frequent k-mers in Text
   def FrequentWords(Text, k):
       FrequentPatterns = []
       Count = CountDict(Text, k)
       m = max(Count.values())
       for i in Count:
           if Count[i] == m:
               FrequentPatterns.append(Text[i:i+k]
       FrequentPatternsNoDuplicates = remove_duplicates(FrequentPatterns)
       return FrequentPatternsNoDuplicates
   ```

Comment: Перечитал вопрос 3 раза, но так и не понял суть вопроса... `"Цифра которая задает количество повторяющихся букв(в примере выше задана цифра"` - какая цифра? в каком примере?

Comment: я наверное неправильно выразился. Text = ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT k = 4 CATG GCAT - это самые часто употребляемые комбинации 4 символов в Text.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Algorithm to find the most common substrings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14670632/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Думаю, что биоинформатика подразумевает эффективное решение, т.к. строки генома могут быть очень длинными.

А одним из эффективных решений, особенно для больших k, в данном случае будет использование суффиксного массива в связке с определением наибольшего общего префикса двух соседних суффиксов (LCP). Построение суффиксного массива несложными средствами имеет сложность `O(NlogN)` или `O(Nlog^2(N))`. Есть и более сложные в реализации алгоритмы за линейное время.

**Edit:**
В коде закомментирована краткая реализацию на Python c плохой асимптотикой.
Заменил на реализацию алгоритма Manber-Myers [отсюда](https://louisabraham.github.io/notebooks/suffix_arrays.html) (должна быть асимптотика O(NlogN), но, как я понял, реализация этого не обеспечивает для произвольных входных данных)

LCP строится за линейное время - я привел эффективный и простой алгоритм Kасаи.

После построения LCP нужно из него вычленить наиболее длинные серии, все элементы которых не меньше заданной длины k (думаю, на Python это делается одной строчкой). Время линейное.

Длина наибольшей серии соответствует (точнее - на единицу меньше) количеству повторов самой частой подстроки нужной длины. Для получения самой этой подстроки нужно взять подстроку, начиная с индекса из соответствующего элемента суффиксного массива.

```
#медленная реализация
#def get_suffix_array(s):
#    return sorted(range(len(s)), key=lambda i: s[i:])

from collections import defaultdict

def sort_bucket(s, bucket, order):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i in bucket:
        key = s[i + order // 2:i + order]
        d[key].append(i)
    result = []
    for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
        if len(v) > 1:
            result += sort_bucket(s, v, 2 * order)
        else:
            result.append(v[0])
    return result


def suffix_array_ManberMyers(s):
    return sort_bucket(s, range(len(s)), 1)

def lcp_kasai(s, suffarr):
    n = len(suffarr)
    k = 0
    lcp = [0] * n
    rank = [0] * n
    for i in range(n):
        rank[suffarr[i]] = i

    for  i in range(n):
        if (k>0):
            k -= 1
        if(rank[i]==n-1):
             k = 0
             continue
        j = sa[rank[i]+1]
        while((i+k<n) & (j+k<n) & (s[i+k]==s[j+k])):
            k += 1
        lcp[rank[i]] = k
    return lcp

sa = suffix_array_ManberMyers("ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT$")
print(sa)
lc = lcp_kasai("ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT$", sa)
print(lc)
```

вывод суффиксного массива и lcp:

```
[30, 0, 24, 26, 21, 14, 17, 7, 20, 13, 6, 11, 1, 28, 23, 25, 16, 19, 12, 5, 
 27, 9, 2, 29, 10, 22, 15, 18, 4, 8, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1,
 3, 2, 6, 2, 1, 0]
```

в lcp мы видим два куска длиной два (это означает, что две подстроки встречаются трижды) со значением >=4: `5, 4  и  6, 5`, начинающиеся на 8 и 17 позициях. Эти позиции в суффиксном массиве содержат индексы в исходной строке 20 и 19, чему соответствуют подстроки `CATG` и `GCAT`

Comment: у вас квадратичная реализация get_suffix_array()¶ При сравнениях с реализацией в лоб,  полезно посмотреть при каких больших n, алгоритм с лучшей асимптотикой становится лучше в фактических  измерениях.

Comment: на Питоне 2 можно было бы легко сделать алгоритм O(n log n) вместо вашего `O(n * n)` с помощью buffer функции, [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13574862/4279)

Comment: Да, я об этом и написал.

Comment: Если у вас одна из частей квадратична, то не имеет значения, что другая линейная.

Comment: Я в курсе. Добавлю реализацию алгоритма Manber-Myers

Comment: осталось только производительность померить, чтобы узнать при каком `n`  алгоритм с лучшей асимптотикой лучше становится (для относительно маленьких строк или таких что в памяти компьютера типичного не поместятся).

Comment: Тут ещё k играет роль - для коротких подстрок и маленького алфавита словарь из вашего подхода будет невелик и скорость хороша. А для практических задач есть `sais` от Yuta Mori (не знаю, можно ли его использовать из Python upd: можно, врапперы есть)

Answer (score 4):

Простой алгоритм в лоб: подсчитать количество вхождений для каждой [перекрывающейся] подстроки длиной `k`, а затем вывести подстроку с наибольшим количеством повторений:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Find most common substring of length k."""
from collections import Counter

text = "ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT"
k = 4

# count occurrences of all k-mers: words of length k in the text
words = Counter(text[i:i+k] for i in range(len(text) - k + 1))  # O(n*k)
print(words.most_common(1)[0][0])  #-> GCAT
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython_stdlib.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
from collections import Counter
from browser import document

@document["mybutton"].bind("click")
def on_click(event):
    text = document['text'].value
    k = int(document['k'].value)
    words = Counter(text[i:i+k] for i in range(len(text) - k + 1))
    print(words.most_common()[0][0])

on_click('dummy on start')
</script><label for="k">k&nbsp;=</label>&nbsp;<input id="k" value="4"> <label for="text">text&nbsp;=</label>&nbsp;<input id="text" value="ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT"> <button id="mybutton">Найти k-мер</button></body>
```

Comment: Мне понравилась простота цикла для получения подпоследовательностей, вы не против, если я ее для моего примера в ответе использую?

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

text = 'ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT'
key_len = 4

accumulator = Counter(text[i: i + key_len] for i in range(len(text) - key_len + 1))

print(accumulator)  # {'A': 7, 'C': 6, 'G': 9, 'T': 7,

max_items = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in accumulator.items():
    max_items[v].append(k)

print(max_items)  # ... , 2: ['TGCA', 'ATGA'], 3: ['GCAT', 'CATG']})

# Находим ключ с максимальным значением
max_key = max(max_items)
print(max_key, max_items[max_key])  # 3 ['GCAT', 'CATG']
```

Comment: спасибо, теперь понятно. Я еще не изучал collections и не знал Counter и defaultdict.

Comment: @AntonZubochenko `Counter` подсчитывает элементы коллекции, а defaultdict устанавливает значением по умолчанию при обращении по ключу, т.е. в момент вызова `max_items[v]` по ключу `v` был создан и возвращен список, если ключа не было, иначе просто возвращен список

Comment: Пока не разобрался в чем дело, но работает некорректно. Если тестить на вот этом геноме: CAGTGGCAGATGACATTTTGCTGGTCGACTGGTTACAACAACGCCTGGGGCTTTTGAGCAACGA GACTTTTCAATGTTGCACCGTTTGCTGCATGATATTGAAAACAATATCACCAAATAAATAACGC CTTAGTAAGTAGCTTTT То ответ неверный. Должен быть ТТТТ, очевидно последние 4 символа не считаются. Есть подозрение, что должно быть: accumulator = Counter(text[i: i + key_len] for i in range(len(text) - key_len+1)) т.к. нумерация идет в пайтоне с 0.

Comment: @AntonZubochenko Посмотрю в чем дело, в ответе jfs тоже, получается такая-же проблема? Попробуйте: `accumulator = Counter(text[i: i + key_len] for i in range(len(text) - key_len + 1))`. Обновил ответ, вроде бы теперь правильно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте нечто вроде:

```
def CountDict(Text, k):
    # Создаём полный список всех подстрок длиной k
    if k > len(Text): return None
    if k == len(Text): return {Text:1}

    list_substr = list()   # Список подстрок длиной k
    for j in range(len(Text) - k + 1):
        list_substr.append( Text[j:j+k])

    # Список превращаем в словарь, с подсчётом частот
    RetMap = dict()
    for j in range(len(list_substr)):
        key_val = list_substr[j]
        RetMap[key_val] = RetMap.get(key_val, 0) + 1

    return RetMap

dnk_map = CountDict('ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT', 4)
print(dnk_map)
```

Answer (score -1):

еще один вариант (сложность алгоритма затрудняюсь оценить):

```
from itertools import product
text = "ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT"

cnt = [[i,text.count(''.join(i))] for i in product('ACGT',repeat=4)]
m = max(cnt,key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
patterns = [''.join(i) for i,_ in filter(lambda x: x[1]==m,cnt)]

print(patterns) # ['CATG', 'GCAT']
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ» пожалуйста удалите.