# Самый длинная повторяющаяся подпоследовательность

Tags: c#, тестирование

Я сделал программу, она работает как задумано, но она не проходит тесты на сайте, только 3/10(https://tutor.amcbridge.com/#/Projects/491bca5d-fc13-8261-DCD0-D68C1280FF43). Скорее всего, я что-то упустил или неправильно понял условие. На всех тестовых случаях, которые я придумал, это работает так, как и должно. Можете ли вы помочь найти случай, в котором он не работает. В программе использовался алгоритм Rabin-Carp и бинарный поиск

**Описание**

Предположим, что приведена последовательность целочисленных чисел с n -элементами. Массив целых чисел B с k<n -элементами называется повторным подмассивом последовательности A[0], …, A[n-1], если существуют как минимум два индекса i и j, 0 ≤ i < j ≤ n-k, такие, что оба подмассива {A[i], A[i+1], …, A[i+k-1]} и {A[j], A[j+1], …, A[j+k-1]}  эквивалентны B. Например, последовательность {1 2 1 2 1} имеет повторяющиеся подпоследовательности: {1}, {2}, {1 2}, {2 1}, {1 2 1}.

Найдите самый длинный повторный подмассив.

**Ввод**

Члены последовательности, целые числа от 1 до 255.

Терминирующее число 0.

**Вывод**

Целое число, длина самого длинного повторного подмассив.

**Пример**

Ввод:

```
1 2 1 2 1 0
```

Output:

```
3
```

Код:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine().Split('0')[0];    //take symbols before zero
        var numbers = input.Trim().Split(' ').Select(n => Int32.Parse(n)).ToList<int>();
        Console.Write(LongestDupSubstring(numbers).Count);
    }

    public static List<int> LongestDupSubstring(List<int> s)
    {
        var lds = new List<int>();
        var n = s.Count;

        var left = 1;
        var right = n;

        while (left <= right)
        { 
            var mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

            var dup = GetDup(mid, s);

            if (dup != null)
            {
                lds = dup;
                left = mid + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                right = mid - 1;
            }
        }

        return lds;
    }

    private static List<int> GetDup(int mid, List<int> s)
    {
        var hash = Hash(s.Take(mid).ToList<int>());

        var set = new HashSet<long> { hash };

        var pow = 1L;

        for (var i = 1; i < mid; i++)
            pow *= 31;

        var n = s.Count;

        for (var i = 0; i < n - mid; ++i)
        { //O(n)
            hash = NextHash(pow, hash, s[i], s[i + mid]);

            if (!set.Add(hash))
                return s.Skip(i +1).Take(mid).ToList<int>();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static long Hash(List<int> s)
    {
        var h = 0L;
        var a = 1L;

        var n = s.Count;

        for (var k = n; k >= 1; k--)
        {
            var ch = s[k - 1];
            h += (ch - 'a' + 1) * a;
            a *= 31;
        }

        return h;
    }

    private static long NextHash(long pow, long hash, int left, int right)
    {
        return (hash - (left - 'a' + 1) * pow) * 31 + (right - 'a' + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем это в алгоритме? `var mid = left + (right - left) / 2;`?

Answer (score 0):

Постройте [суффиксный массив](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/suffix_array#7) и посчитайте на нём LCP (длины наибольших общих префиксов соседних суффиксов). Самое большое значение в LCP - то, что нужно

Вторая задача описана по той же ссылке, или можно посмотреть алгоритм Касаи ([на Python с примером применения здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/860817/291659), н[а Java в вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B8#:%7E:text=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B8%20(%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%E2%80%94,%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0).) )